# How to dynamically add text during insert mode in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

What I want to do is to make a clean structure for adding comments in my file, like this :

```
/*********************
 * This is a comment *
 *********************/
```

I've managed to add the initial structure required to start commenting which is :

```
/**********
 * [TEXT] *
 **********/
```

using snipMate. But now, whenever I enter any text in the region `[TEXT]`, for each character I enter, an asterisk should be added in the line above and below (hope you can get my point).

I think I can achieve this using the key mapping `imap` but not sure how to approach this. Even then, I think it will be a bit slow, so is there any way I can achieve this by vim programming? I just want someone to point me in the right direction.

If there is any plugin available for this, mention that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the snipMate plugin provides *mirroring* (i.e. copying the typed contents of the current placeholder to another position), it has no ability to run transformations on it (and this is needed here: you want each typed character to be translated into an asterisk). This should be possible with the more modern [UltiSnips - The ultimate snippet solution for python enabled Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) plugin.

Nonetheless, I would ask you to reconsider your approach to "clean" commenting. If your style requires special setup with a custom plugin in a particular editor, chances are that your colleagues / collaborators won't have the same setup, and are therefore likely to ignore your scheme. That could be even you, when you're forced to make edits on another computer / editor. IMO, you don't lose much in beauty, but gain a lot in maintainability if you stick to simpler formatting, like this:

```
/****************************************
  This is a comment
****************************************/
```

In particular, dropping the trailing, right-aligned `*` enables you to quickly reformat comments with `gq`.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a 75-wide block like this:

```
/***********************************/
/***********************************/
/***********************************/
```

Saved in a named register ("e" but could be anything). I then just paste it when needed and overwrite ("r"replace) the center line with comment text.

Not scripted but fast and effective. If I need a different comment method, say "#" for Python, it's trivial to swap the contents of the "e" register.

Answer (score 1):

I use this mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>g I// <Esc>A //<Esc>yyp0llv$hhhr-yykPjj
```

to turn

```
hsdjsfdsgdfsdgfsdgf
```

into

```
//---------------------//
// hsdjsfdsgdfsdgfsdgf //
//---------------------//
```

I'm sure you could change it easily to match your banner style.